# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Tags: javascript

i get this Error   `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`  from below JavaScript code that intended to highlights the hash-link when i scroll down to the section with the same id as in the hash-link.

What wrong with the code ? and how can i get out of that Error

```js
// cache the navigation links
var navigationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('#navigation > ul > li > a');
// cache all sections 
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section[id]');
// iterrate in reverse order and map each section id to their corresponding navigation link
var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
for (var i = sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var sectionId = sections[i].id;
  sectionIdTonavigationLink[sectionId];
  //attach section id's to navLinks
  sectionIdTonavigationLink[sectionId] = '#navigation > ul > li > a [href=\\#' + sectionId + ']';
}

function highlightNavigation() {
  // get the current vertical position of the scroll bar
  var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

  // iterate the sections
  sections.forEach(function(items) {
    var currentSection = items;
    // get the position of the section
    var sectionTop = currentSection.offsetTop;
    // if the user has scrolled over the top of the section  
    if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
      // get the section id
      var id = currentSection.getAttribute('id');
      // get the corresponding navigation link
      var navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
      // if the link is not active
      if (!navigationLink.classList.contains('active')) {
        // remove .active class from all the links
        navigationLinks.classList.remove('active');
        // add .active class to the current link
        navigationLink.classList.add('active');
      }
      // we have found our section, so we return false to exit the each loop
      return false;
    }
  });
}
window.onscroll = highlightNavigation;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: The values of the properties in `sectionIdTonavigationLink` are strings, not DOM elements. They don't have a `classList` property.

Comment: `sectionIdTonavigationLink[sectionId];` does nothing on its own 
`sectionIdTonavigationLink[sectionId] = '#navigation > ul > li > a [href=\\#' + sectionId + ']';` does not get an object  - it is just a string.
Perhaps you mean `sectionIdTonavigationLink[sectionId] = document.querySelector('#navigation > ul > li > a [href=\\#' + sectionId + ']');`

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. There's only one place in your code where you use `.contains()`. So, whatever you use `.contains()` on is undefined. Namely, `navigationLink.classList`.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille  Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: code makes no sense, you select all the links so you have reference to the objects and then you for some reason create selectors?

Comment: @epascarello  i wan't to add active class to navigation links

Comment: `var navigationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('#navigation > ul > li > a');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section[id]');
var sectionIdToNavigationLink = Array.from(sections).reduce(function (acc, section, index) { acc[section].id = navigationLinks[index]; return acc;});`

Comment: See? You're narrowing it down. `Cannot read property 'classList' of null` means `navigationLink` is null.

Comment: @epascarello  from the solution above , will i be able to add active class to navigation links ???

Comment: @Jeremy Thille ok but  i just wan'ted to add and remove class to navlinks  according to my case

Comment: @Jeremy Thille  i hope you've notice that  , problem comes from this line     var navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
      // if the link is not active
      if (!navigationLink.classList.contains('active')) {
        // remove .active class from all the links
        navigationLinks.classList.remove('active');
        // add .active class to the current link
        navigationLink.classList.add('active');
      }